# Are there any formal systems or programming languages in which its only possible to define functions that have inverses?

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem, functional-programming, decidability, reversible-computing

Consider an algorithm $f(x)$.

Are there formal systems or programming languages that only allow $f(x)$ to be defined if $f^-1(x)$ exists?

Comment: Do you want to find $f^{-1}$ or to know if it exists?

Comment: I'd like to know that given $f$, $f^-1$ exists, and then produce it, all automatically

Comment: How is $f$ specified as input?  What are the domain and range of $f$?  What do you mean by "possible"?  Are you asking whether the problem is decidable?  If you want to produce it automatically, that should be mentioned in the question.  Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I had a go at improving it, let me know if it still needs more clarity

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you want an algorithm for deciding some problem, what are the inputs to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?  Is the input a Turing machine or algorithm that defines $f$?  Is $f^{-1}$ also provided as input?  What does it mean for $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ to mean if the algorithm for $f$ or $f^{-1}$ doesn't halt on its input?  What do you mean by 'given it..."?  You might want to break this down into multiple smaller sentences.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion, I have tried it again.

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. Better tell us what you are trying to achieve. This said, you are quite free to work with "the set of the invertible functions". As regards a programming language based on this concept, I have strong doubts about any usefulness it could have.

Comment: After checking your edits, I think that the current version of the question is worse.

Comment: So "int function add (int x, int y) { return x + y; }" is not allowed?

Comment: But on the other hand, you can undo RSA encryption? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are.  See [reversible computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing).  You could of course design a programming language that only allows using reversible operations (e.g., Toffoli gates), though I'm skeptical whether this would be useful in practice.  Searching on "reversible programming language" finds a bunch of academic work on the subject.  See, e.g., the [Janus programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus_(time-reversible_computing_programming_language)).

I'm skeptical that you're going to find this useful for practical applications.